# Bound on third moment

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

I'd like to show that if $\mathsf{E}(Z^4)=1$, then $\mathsf{E}(Z^3)\leqslant 1$.

I've been trying to use Jensen's inequality to show this, but haven't managed.

Answer (score 1):

$$|E[Z^3]|\leqslant E[|Z|^3]\leqslant E[Z^4]^{3/4}$$

Comment: And now the real mystery: how can anyone "try to use Jensen's inequality to show this, but (fail to) manage"?

Comment: @Glassjawed No, not right. If $E[Z^4]=1$, then $-1\leqslant E[Z^3]\leqslant1$. Always. Whether $E[Z]\geqslant0$ or $E[Z]\leqslant0$. (Did you read my answer? It shows this.)